# Making an API call using fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to make a Fetch API call using a free code snippet from and I am unable to receive the JSON response. I would have thought it was just a question of placing the code snippet between the script tags on the index.html page,

```js
fetch("https://currency-converter5.p.rapidapi.com/currency/list?format=json", {
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "x-rapidapi-host": "currency-converter5.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "**redacted**"
  }
})
.then(response => {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're close.  But there's a second asynchronous operation that needs to be chained into the promise.  Your `response` contains JSON, which can be read (asynchronously) with `response.json()`.  Return that and chain another `.then()` to log the result of that operation:

```
fetch("https://currency-converter5.p.rapidapi.com/currency/list?format=json", 
{
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "x-rapidapi-host": "currency-converter5.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "**redacted**"
  }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(result => {
  console.log(result);
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks David for the quick response, I am still a little bit lost where to place this code snippet in the index.html file. Is it just placed between the Script tags? I tried running this code on JS bin and still receive no response

Comment: @BenjaminMasters: It's standard JavaScript, so anywhere in a `<script>` element should work.  Perhaps something else is going wrong?  It works on this page when used as a code snippet.  (It's no longer a code snippet since it won't work with your API key redacted.)  Now may be the time to open your browser's debugging tools and see what you can find.  Any errors on the development console?  If you place breakpoints using the script debugger, is the code invoked?  Are the chained callbacks invoked?